# Converting date operation from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following SELECT statement in MySQL:

```
floor(datediff(i.created_at, curdate()) / 7) AS weeks_ago,
```

Am I converting this correctly to PostgreSQL?

```
TRUNC(DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_DATE - i.created_at )/7)  AS weeks_ago,
```

Comment: [PostreSQL](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-floor/) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) `Floor` functions appear identical. Why do you suspect they are different?

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
What is your problem? This may be an X Y problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL query seems to calculate the difference between two dates and divides the result by 7. Expecting, that you want to calculate the number of weeks between two dates. But with negative sign, because you are subtracting the smaller date from the current one:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd161525cd236a78a244a3e455a4fe81)

---

But the PostgreSQL query does not work: The difference between two dates already is the number of days between them. So you are calling the function `date_part('day', <INTEGER VALUE>)`. This function does not exist. `date_part(`) is expecting a datetime type.

So, transform your MySQL query into Postgres could be:

```
SELECT floor(('your date' - CURRENT_DATE)::numeric / 7)
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=43a88d46f715dd4097588786c46fb1f2)

The `floor()` functions of both DBMS, of course, do exactly the same thing. In Postgres you need to explictitly cast the `integer` value from the date difference into a non-integer type which supports decimal digits to avoid an integer division.

---

**Notice**: I would switch the date values in both difference operations to avoid the negative result.